# I'm trying to import a `.txt file` into a workbook from another workbook but i have some mistakes

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say i'm working on workbook A and workbook A produce a `.txt file`.
I also have workbook B witch contain a table that is ready to receive data from a `.txt file`.
i want to import the `.txt file`produce by workbook A into workbook B and i want to do so with workbook A
here's my code:

```
Sub result_template()

Dim FL, LL, CT As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim restemplate As Object
Dim sourceBook As Workbook

CT = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    If MsgBox("Are you on the good bus compare tool?", 3 + 48 + 256, "check the active workbook") = vbNo Then
        GoTo PROC_EXIT
    Else
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)   '
            .Title = "Select the log file"                 'Open the file explorer
            .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"     'for you to select
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails            'the file you want
            .AllowMultiSelect = False                          'to format
            .Show

            If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then LL = .SelectedItems(1)
            MsgBox LL
        End With

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)   '
            .Title = "Select the result template"              'Open the file explorer
            .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"         'for you to select
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails            'the file you want
            .AllowMultiSelect = False                          'to format
            .Show

            If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then FL = .SelectedItems(1)
            MsgBox FL
        End With
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
        new_LL = Right(LL, InStr(1, LL, "\"))

        new_FL = Right(FL, Len(FL) - InStrRev(FL, "\"))

        CT = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(FL)
            Windows(new_FL).Activate
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;LL", Destination:=Range("$A$3"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Windows(CT).Activate
End If
PROC_EXIT:
End Sub
```

Excel is not able to locate LL (Log Location) is there something i'm doing wrong?

If you find a simpler way to wright my code please let me know!

Comment: I might be blind - which line has an arrow?

Comment: oups totaly forgot the arrow

Comment: For anyone else who might be slightly blind, it's the line `.CommandType = 0`.

Comment: "You can set the CommandType property only if the value of the QueryType property for the query table or PivotTable cache is xlOLEDBQuery." - from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.commandtype).

Comment: will it change something if i delete it ?? and does it have something to do with the fact that Excel is unable to locate my file?

Comment: No it seems like you should delete here.

Comment: @BigBen thanks! and do you see why Excel is unable to locate my LL? Btw the LL is the path of my Log file.

Comment: If you are referring to `"TEXT;LL"` - it looks like you need to concatenate with `&` - `LL` inside quotes is the text "LL", not your variable.